# Location Manager very slow and fails - how to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have implemented the Location Manager class into my app to get the user's location. I have installed the app onto my iPhone 14 device (not sim) and sometimes getting the current location is slow and sometimes fails and doesn't fetch. I tried modifying the code by adding additional cases if the location manager sends a nil completion but that didn't really help. I think there may be something wrong with the set up of the class. I'd appreciate any help.

```swift
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject {
    private var manager: CLLocationManager?
    private var completion: ((String?) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func requestLocation(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion

        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager?.delegate = self
        manager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    }
}

extension LocationManager : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first(where: { $0.horizontalAccuracy <= manager.desiredAccuracy }) {
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
                var postalCode: String? = nil
                if error == nil {
                    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                        postalCode = placemark.postalCode
                    }
                }
                self.completion?(postalCode)
                self.completion = nil
                self.manager = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        self.completion?(nil)
        self.completion = nil
        self.manager = nil
    }

    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager){
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .denied:
            self.completion?(nil)
            self.completion = nil
            self.manager = nil
        case .notDetermined:
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            self.completion?(nil)
            self.completion = nil
            self.manager = nil
        @unknown default:
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is generally correct. You don't mention what is actually happening at runtime. There are many cases where you call the completion handler with a result of `nil` but you make no attempt to indicate why it failed. You are also asking for high accuracy and that always takes longer, especially if you are indoors while testing. Add print statements so you can see what it actually happening.

Comment: @HangarRash do you think changing it to "kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer" would make it noticeably quicker?

Comment: It might be faster but is it accurate enough for your needs? You could get the wrong postal code in some cases. Don't forget that your speed issue is also due to the geocoding. That's a whole other level of delay. Just make sure you are doing your tests outside where you get good location results.

Comment: why do you "call" this `manager.stopUpdatingLocation()` .. in the delegate didUpdateLocations ?

Comment: @TonyMkenu The OP only wants one location so it can be geocoded to get its postal code.